# Building a table without having to apply $f(x)$ repeatedly

Tags: list-manipulation

I have $f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R^m$ and I want to create a table as follows

$$
\begin{align}
\text{variable} && \text{value} && \text{numbers} && \text{negatives} \\
x && f(x) && a && b
\end{align}
$$

where $a$ is the number of components in $f(x)$ that are actually numbers (my $f$ involves `Solve` and in a few instances it doesn't return numbers) and $b$ the number that are negative. I have all the variables in list `x` (so each `x[[i]]` is $x$) and I was thinking of writing something like

```
Table[{x[[i]],f(x[[i]]),Count[f(x[[i]]),u_/;NumberQ[u]],Count[f(x[[i]]),u_/;u<0]},{i,1,Lenght[x]}]
```

but I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

**Edit:**

As per Szabolcs request, I'm posting my full code

```
A = {{1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 4}, {1, 5, 5}, {2, 3, 4}};
qVec = Array[q, 4]; 
lVec = Array[l, 3];
mVec = Array[m, 4];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, 4];
c = 1/2;
needs = qVec^(1/c).A;
step = 1/3;
p = Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[1, {3}, Range[-2/3, 5/3, step]],1];
num = Length[p];
f = DeleteDuplicates[Table[Minimize[{needs.p[[i]], qVec.onesVec == 1, 
   Thread[qVec >= 0]}, qVec][[2]], {i, 1, num}]];
num = Length[f];
Table[
 {qVec /. f[[i]], 
  lVec /. Flatten[Solve[Flatten[{Thread[D[qVec.onesVec - lVec.needs - mVec.qVec, {qVec}]== 0], Thread[mVec*qVec == 0]}] /. f[[i]], 
 Flatten[{lVec, mVec}]]], 
  Count[lVec /.Flatten[Solve[Flatten[{Thread[D[qVec.onesVec - lVec.needs - mVec.qVec, {qVec}] == 0], Thread[mVec*qVec == 0]}] /. f[[i]], 
 Flatten[{lVec, mVec}]]], u_ /; u < 0], 
  Count[lVec /. Flatten[Solve[Flatten[{Thread[D[qVec.onesVec - lVec.needs - mVec.qVec, {qVec}] == 0], Thread[mVec*qVec == 0]}] /. f[[i]], 
 Flatten[{lVec, mVec}]]], u_ /; NumberQ[u]]}, {i, 1, num}]
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. Post *working* code.

Comment: `Table[f[x],{x,xList}]` is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to limit the calls of the function $f$, perhaps with something like:

```
Table[{x, #, Count[#, u_/;NumberQ[u]], Count[#, u_/;u<0]}& [f[x]], {x, xList}]
```